# Filter and transform rxjs BehaviorSubject

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
const subject = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null);
subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);

subject.pipe(
  filter(x => x !== null),
  take(1),                           // <--- VSCode shows an error here
  switchMap((x: number) => of(10)),
);
```

After filtering, the stream's type is still `number | null` (instead of `number`).

So VSCode shows an error for `take`:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'

Is it possible to change a stream's type after filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), `filter` gets typed correctly:

```
const isNumber = (n: number | null): n is number => n !== null

subject.pipe(
  filter(isNumber),
  take(1),
  switchMap((x: number) => of(10)),
);
```

You can also use a type predicate in `filter((x): x is number => x !== null)` but that's a bit less readable.

Comment: Thanks this works! Actually I like the second form as it's more concise! :-) I'm confused though... The filter only passes through numbers, but the type guard states that the type is number, before the filter is performed!? How does that work?

Comment: The `n is number` part is the return type of the arrow function, normally it would say `boolean`. You're helping the compiler a bit by stating that if the guard returns true, the type of `n` will be `number`.